# How to Merge N sort two text files

Tags: java, sorting, merge

I have to read in two texts files that look something like this....

FileOne: 10  1 2 3 4 5 67 75 47 18

FileTwo: 5 65 74 57 68 28 38

The first number represents the count of how many of these integers I should use to populate my array.

I need to read the first line of the file then use that number to populate the two arrays with however many elements specified.

I have figured out how to read in both text files and concatenate them together, however I can't figure out how to only get the first number from the file and use it to determine how many numbers I should use after that.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReadData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the first file name: ");
        String input = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the second file name: ");
        String input2 = s.nextLine();

        int[] data = readFiles(input);
        int[] data2 = readFiles(input2);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data2));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(concat(data, data2)));
    }   

    public static int[] readFiles(String file) {

        try {

            File f = new File(file);
            Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
            int counter = 0;
            while(s.hasNextInt()) {
                counter++;
                s.nextInt();
            }
            int[] arr = new int[counter];

            Scanner s1 = new Scanner(f);

            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                arr[i] = s1.nextInt();

            return arr;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }   
    }
    static int[] concat(int[]... arrays) {
    int length = 0;
    for (int[] array : arrays) {
        length += array.length;
    }
    int[] result = new int[length];
    int pos = 0;
    for (int[] array : arrays) {
        for (int element : array) {
            result[pos] = element;
            pos++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: File one has 9 numbers after the 10, file two has 6 numbers after the 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I'd suggest reading the entire line as a single string, then parse it using a parser which will use space as a delimiter. You will get a DS containing all of your numbers in a more elegant solution.
(Java parsing simple solution : http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html)

Once you have the DS containing the numbers, you can iterate on it at your pleasure, remembering that the first value determines the amount of future iterations on the DS.

Assuming you use java 8, I'd suggest using the stream functionalities in order to do so : http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

Comment if you require any furthor elaborations and good luck.